# python3 converting unreadable character to readable chracter

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, decode, type-conversion

hi i have a text file and i am reading file and parsing datas,
but my file contains some text like

```
\u03a4\u03c1\u03b5\u03b9\u03c2 \u03bd\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03bf\u03af \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc \u03c0\u03c4\u03ce\u03c3\u03b7 \u03bf\u03b2\u03af\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2 \u03c3\u03b5 \u03c3\u03c0\u03af\u03c4\u03b9 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf \u03a3\u03b9\u03bd\u03ac
```

how can i convert a it readable text with python
i try to use these codes to solve but it doesn't work

```
def encodeDecode(self, data):
    new_data = ''
    for ch in data:
        #let = ch.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
        #new_data += let
        new_data += repr(ch)[1:2]
    return new_data
```

Comment: First of all what you mean by unreadable? is there any problem with it? second what you want to do with your data? do you wan to print it or write in a file?

Comment: this is my text which is unreadeble \u03a4\u03c1\u03b5\u03b9\u03c2 \u03bd\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03bf\u03af \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc \u03c0\u03c4\u03ce\u03c3\u03b7 \u03bf\u03b2\u03af\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2 \u03c3\u03b5 \u03c3\u03c0\u03af\u03c4\u03b9 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf \u03a3\u03b9\u03bd\u03ac

Comment: i want to make it readble like öİÇ something like that and i want to write it on a file

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your string,you have a unicode data.Just based on how you want to use it you can decode it custom or using python default encoding for example if you want to print it, since strings in python 3 are unicode you can just print it.

```
>>> s="""\u03a4\u03c1\u03b5\u03b9\u03c2 \u03bd\u03b5\u03ba\u03c1\u03bf\u03af \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc \u03c0\u03c4\u03ce\u03c3\u03b7 \u03bf\u03b2\u03af\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2 \u03c3\u03b5 \u03c3\u03c0\u03af\u03c4\u03b9 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf \u03a3\u03b9\u03bd\u03ac """
>>> 
>>> print s
Τρεις νεκροί από πτώση οβίδας σε σπίτι στο Σινά 
>>>
```

But if you want to write your data in a file you need to use a proper encoding for your file.

You can do it with passing your encoding to [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function when you open a file for writing.

Answer (score -1):

You could also convert it using Python's json module - this would also work in Python 2x

```
>>> f = open('input.txt', 'r')
>>> json_str = '"%s"' % f.read().replace('"', '\\"') # wrap the input string in double quotes
>>> print(json.loads(json_str))
Τρεις νεκροί από πτώση οβίδας σε σπίτι στο Σινά
```